# Select first item with the same value on MuiSelect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a dropdown select of languages with the top languages on top, a divider, then the full list of languages, top languages included.

[image]

Since the top languages will have the same value as the ones in the language list, I want it so that if I select one of the top languages in the dropdown select, what'll show and be highlighted is the option on top, not the one located in the full list.

Comment: Your explanation is little confusing. So you mean to say when user selects any of the languages from the list should be added in top list (highlighted text) and the value of the top languages should be the same if user selects from the full-list?
 Can you attach your code snippet?

Comment: Sorry about that. Here's an example of what I was talking about: https://i.imgur.com/1gUpor6.png

If I were to select language 123, instead of selecting the first MenuItem with the value of language 123, what will be selected is the last MenuItem with the value of language 123. I hope I make sense right now.